# Python Regex: don't match if containing some string

Tags: python, regex

I'm using python regex on these two strings:

`t1 = 'foo 36 months bar'`

`t2 = 'bar Not suitable for children under 36 months foo'`

I want to match '36 months' on t1, and not match t2 because it has 'Not suitable for children under' before the '36 months.

After searching I have this:

`regex = re.compile(r'((?!Not suitable for children under) 36 month)')`

But it matches both. How do adapt this so it doesn't match a string with 'Not suitable for children under' before the ' 36 months'?

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is a negative look*ahead*.
However, what you're trying to find is when some text exists before what you want to match.
So instead use a negative look*behind*:

```
re.search('(?<!Not suitable for children under) 36 months',t1)
```

Demonstration:

```
In [13]: re.search('(?<!Not suitable for children under) 36 months',t1)                             
Out[13]: <re.Match object; span=(3, 13), match=' 36 months'>

In [14]: re.search('(?<!Not suitable for children under) 36 months',t2)
```